# MySQL-Error: Unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

```
<div class="ui-widget">

<form method="POST">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search'])){

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '1234');
mysql_select_db('hoppers');

    $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE {$_POST['username']} = user_name";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("MySQL-Error: " . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


if($row = TRUE){

        $present = $row['user_name'];
        echo $present;

     }else{
            echo "This User does not exist!";
        }
}
?>

<label for="tags">Username: </label>
<input type="text" id="tags" name = "username">
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Suchen!">
</form>
</div>
```

So I'm always getting the this error-message: **MySQL-Error: Unknown column 'dompol171' in 'where clause'**.
So it is comparing the username that I entered with the column "user_name" itself. I keep freaking out...since I have no clue how to compare it in a different way!

Comment: Where's all the obligatory stuff about using mysqli?  Isn't mysql_query() still deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is the value of `$_POST['username']` is being considered a column since you didn't quote it i.e. set it as a string. So say the user name is musa, its trying to compare column musa to column user_name(and that column doesn't exist). It should be

```
 $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE 'some username' = user_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='" . $username . "'";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using :

```
 $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '{$_POST['username']}'";
```

Comment: this gives me this error code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: so this wont change anything...it will still not compare!

Comment: How is you SQL statement ? (I edited my answer twice)

Comment: $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '{$_POST['username']}'";
this seems to work...actually I'm having problems with echoing the result...

Answer (score -1):

You have made a mistake in where clause , it's :

`WHERE user_name = {$_POST['username']}";`

The syntaxe is : `Where "column" = "value"`

Answer (score -1):

You have your parameters backwards. Column name *always* goes before the value:

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = {$_POST['username']}";
```

This isn't a comparison operator like in PHP where the operands can be on either side of the equation.

Comment: Are you sure about that?